# More than one path from A*?

Tags: a-star

I have written an A* that works nice. It gives me the shortest path between two nodes. However, I would like to have two or maybe even three paths. The best, the second best and the third path (if there is more than one path available). Kinda like directions on Google Maps where you can see multiple options between two cities.

Is this possible with A* or am I stuck with only getting the best result? If it is possible, please point me in the right direction. If not possible with A*, what algorithm should I look at that can do this?

My implementation of A* is from the pseudocode on wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode), and is written in VB .NET. If that is of any importance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the exact second-shortest path requires something like [this](http://hatemabdelghani.wordpress.com/2009/07/04/second-shortest-path/).

If you don't care about that kind of precision, then you can introduce a bit of randomness into the shortest path:

1. Cut a vertex or edge from the shortest path and recompute.
2. At some point along the shortest path, make an intentional wrong turn somewhere and recompute from there.

Comment: Thank you, this pointed me in a good direction.With my shortest path, for each node/city in this path so did I recompute the A* again with the current node/city added directly into the closed set to see if I ended up with a new path.

Answer (score 1):

when you perform A* search you change state of priority queue. When you come to finish you put away the best vertex nearest to the finish. Also there some other vertices near finish already, you can peek them from the queue too and get "another best path".

But you can get different results: sometimes the paths can diff in only last edge. 
Like this: -------<=>finish. If there is really another best path with similar length then you will find it.

I think Google provides many paths because they use different metrics simultaneously. The metrics give different results and solve path optimization problem using different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Recompute the A* algorithm using the same graph but with different weightings. The weighting on each arc, for the fastest journey, ought to be the time taken to traverse that arc, which is the length of the arc divided by the expected speed to travel along it.

You can create a new set of weightings using only the distance, not the expected speed (it is more convenient to assign the same speed to every arc). That will give the shortest path, not the fastest one.

You can then create a compromise between shortest and fastest. You now have three (possibly) different routes.

Other options:

(i) add a weight to every arc to account for the junctions at start and end; tinker with this weight, allowing you to create routes that minimise turns. You can also add extra weights for very sharp turns, or turns across the traffic flow (right turns in UK, Australia, India, etc.; left turns in USA, France, etc.).

(ii) Create a route that avoids motorways / freeways by setting the cost of them to a very high value.

(iii) Use time of day, or actual on-line information, to estimate traffic flow and modify weightings based on that.